# MVC - validation - should ViewModel have access to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model which should check that label of a new entity is unique (not in DB yet).

At the moment I've done it in the view model class:

```
     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (PowerOrDuty != null)
        {
            if (PowerOrDuty.Identifier == null)
            {
                using (var db = new PowersAndDutiesContext()) 
                {
                    var existingLabels = db.PowersAndDuties.Select(pod => pod.Label);
                    if (existingLabels.Contains(PowerOrDuty.Label))
                    {
                        yield return new ValidationResult("Cannot create a new power or duty because another power or duty with this label already exists");
                    }
                }                    
            }
           ......
```

Please note that this is a small internal app with small DB and my time is limited, so the code is not perfect.

I feel that DB access from view models might be a bad practice. Should view model have direct DB access? Should it be able to call a repository to get the available labels? Should validation requiring DB access be done in a controller instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should view model have direct DB access?

I think this should be avoided at all cost

> Should it be able to call a repository to get the available labels ?

This is not the concern of a ViewModel.
This would introduce some complexity in the testing of your ViewModel (which should almost need none) I guess it is a sign of trouble coming.

> Should validation requiring DB access be done in a controller instead ?

Maybe, if by "DB" you mean "Repository". But what comes to mind is a separate custom validation class that you will be able to (un)plug, test, and reuse, in another controller for ajax validation, etc

Answer (score 1):

I think that accessing DB from VM is not wrong... AFAIK it is not breaking MVC concept (since it is a presentation layer concept).  Said that, it could be better if you have the Validate method provided by a Service Layer.

But all the logic related to the content of the ViewModel, it is better kept in the VM than in the Controller. Cleaner controllers is better.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the ViewModels to be anemic -- simply classes with properties.

For custom server-side validation like this, I prefer it go either in a service, with the consumption of the service in your controller, or even behind a custom validator.

With a custom validator, you could even (optionally) execute the validation remotely. That gets a little more complex though, but I've done it using a generic remote validator that consumes an Ajax action method to perform the validation, and wire that up through both the client validator and remote validator (to ensure you have your validation logic in a single method).

But which ever way you go, I think it is more common -- and in my opinion, more clean -- to keep all logic out of your ViewModel. Even in a simple app, your ViewModel should be dumb to your database context. Ideally, only services (not necessarily web services, but just an abstraction layer) are aware of your database context.

This, to me, should be done regardless of the size of application. I think the effort and complexity (it only adds another assembly to your solution) is worth the abstraction you get. Down the road, *if* you happen to decide to consume your services from another application, or if you decide to swap out your database context, it's much easier with that abstraction in place.

Answer (score 1):

Your view model should not be tied to your context, it only cares about displaying data and validating it after a submit. You can perform validation like a required field or a value in range, but you can't know if a label already exists in your database.

You can't also fetch a list of "forbidden labels" before displaying your form, in order to test your label afterwards, because that list could have changed during this time (another user updating you database).

In my opinion, validation at model level should focus on what it can validate without knowledge of the data source, and let your database notify you errors like submitting a duplicate value in a field which has an unique constraint. You'll catch exceptions coming from your database for errors like those, and manage them accordingly.

Anyway, i think there's no straightforward answer for a problem like this.